# Philosophy on Binding to Parameters in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, valueconverter

So I'm trying to build out a project that will allow a user to type some text into a textbox on the left side of the form and that will filter out the available items from my datasource list.

```
<Label Content="Enter item name below"></Label>
<TextBox Name="SearchTermTextBox" TabIndex="0" Text="" />
```

I was under the impression I could bind to the datasource the list then use a converter to filter out the items that were unlike the string.

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Colors}">
   <ListBox.ItemsSource>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterTextValueConverter}" ConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=SearchTermTextBox, Path=Text}" />
   </ListBox.ItemsSource>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       //etc...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, you can't bind to an elementname in the converterparameter unless you use something called a dependency property.

Edit: Seeing as I've created confusion with the code above, here's the converter I'm trying to bind:

```
public class FilterTextValueConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var trackedColors = value as List<Colors>;
        if (trackedColors != null)
            return (trackedColors).Where(item => item.ColorName.Contains(parameter.ToString())).ToList();

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class Colors
{
    public String ColorName;
    public String Description;
}
```

What is wrong with my approach here? Clearly I'm angering the WPF gods since this is a fairly straightforward operation but I'm being denied it on principle. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple binding with converter will work here, no need for MultiBinding.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=SearchTermTextBox,
                          Converter="{StaticResource FilterTextValueConverter}">
   ......
</ListBox>
```

Assuming **`FilterTextValueConverter`** is implementing **`IValueConverter`**, you can access text from value passed to Convert method.

```
public class FilterTextValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value.ToString(); // TEXT for textBox can be accessed here.
        return new List<string>(); // Return filtered list from here.
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case you want to pass multiple bindings to converter, use **`IMultiValueConverter`** because **`ConverterParameter`** is not Dependency property, hence cannot be bound.

*XAML*

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Colors}">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterTextValueConverter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding ElementName="SearchTermTextBox" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

*Converter*

```
public class FilterTextValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var trackedColors = values[0] as List<Colors>;
        if (trackedColors != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()))
            return (trackedColors).Where(item => 
                   item.ColorName.Contains(values[1].ToString())).ToList();

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to bind ConverterParameter to the SearchTermTextBox, and visual studio doesn't allow that. My converter must return a List<Colors>.

Comment: I've edited the original to explain my situation better. I agree that the multi is unnecessary, it was just an experiment in getting it to take.

Comment: Converter parameter cannot be bound. You need to use `IMultiValueConverter`. I have updated the answer for that. See if that helps.

Comment: I happened to land on this late last night, but I'll mark you as the answer. Though I still don't understand why we're not allowed to bind to converterparameter.

Comment: As an aside, can you change your if(trackedColors != null) to 


if (trackedColors != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()))

and return trackedColors instead of null? Just in case someone else runs into this question and wants to implement something similar.

Comment: I just put the code provided by you in question. Any ways I have updated it. Regarding `Though I still don't understand why we're not allowed to bind to converterparameter.` - Because WPF guys made ConverterParameter as normal CLR property and not DP (binding support is only for DP's). Not sure why they did that.

Answer (score 0):

I continued looking into this issue well after the accepted answer was posted and working for me. What I discovered is that it's a fairly trivial task to wrap the control you're trying to get a new dependencyproperty out of to allow for proper binding.

I will not be accepting my own answer to this determined so much later, but this seems (in my amateur opinion) like a much more elegant solution than adding a converter despite being a bit more complex:

Note that this is for a new dependency on the caretindex property of a textbox, not for the original question on binding, but it just requires some smart renaming to get it working ;).

```
    public class TextBoxDependencyWrapper : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaretIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CaretIndex", typeof (int), typeof (TextBoxDependencyWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, CaretIndexChanged ));

        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) //Event that changes the property we're trying to track
        {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) //Event that changes the property we're trying to track
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            CaretIndex = base.CaretIndex;
        }

        public new int CaretIndex
        {
            get { return (int) GetValue(CaretIndexProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaretIndexProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```